# Redis or Memcache with OpenCart

Tags: php, redis, memcached, opencart, opencart2.x

We are using `OpenCart` version 2.x for our site and now as we are going to run marketing campaign we are expecting loads of traffic. Can someone tell me where can I define `Redis/Memcache` in `OpenCart` for session and cache storage manually just like we do for `Magento` in `local.xml` file.

Comment: have you checked OpenCart documentation http://docs.opencart.com? If is not there, maybe its only possible through modules

Comment: I am really afraid that I could not find anything related to this under docs... anyone please who has used Opencart with either Memcache or Redis?

Comment: Session handling is not related to opencart read this : http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php